# Guessing gender from other names in same table

Tags: mysql

Following is my SQLFIDDLE in which you'll see there are names with place ABC who have genders and there are same names but with different place DEF which donot have any gender. What i have been trying to do is to populate the gender of `DEF` based on the gender of the similar name of `ABC`. Kindly let me know how can i do that (IN same table updation) thanks,

**FIDDLE:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6b05/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
UPDATE addr AS a
JOIN addr AS b
  ON  b.Name = a.Name
  AND b.place = 'ABC'
  AND a.place = 'DEF'
SET a.gender = b.gender
WHERE a.gender = 'N/A'
```

---

If `place` doesn't matter

```
UPDATE addr AS a
JOIN addr AS b
  ON  b.Name = a.Name
  AND b.gender <> 'N/A' 
SET a.gender = b.gender
WHERE a.gender = 'N/A'
```

Comment: kindly take a look to it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55c73/1 , this trick is assigning wrong gender, see yin's gender

Comment: My bad, I forgot line 3, `b.Name = a.Name`

Comment: one last question if i want to do it without any check on place, like place can be anyone but if there is name exist then it should set the gender accordingly?

Comment: If you don't want to match the places, you can drop the two `AND` checks.

Comment: i did that but ts not updating accordingly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a910/1 , see for yii